# iOS 8: Sound setting doesn't work for UIUserNotificationType

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uilocalnotification

Am trying a local notification demo and in my iphone the badge & alert notifications works good except sound.Here is my code,

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

       func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

            let notificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationType, categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0  // resetting the badge number to again 0

            return true
        }

        func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {

            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0  //resetting the badge number to again 0

        }
```

here is the mainviewcontroller code snippet

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBAction func startNotification(sender: UIButton) {

        var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
        localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)  // notification will be sent after 5 seconds from clicking
        localNotification.alertBody = "Notification came"
        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone() // Time zone of the notfication's fire date
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1 //The number to diplay on the icon badge. We will increment this number by one.

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification) // scheduling the notification

    }
```

Note: **Even I went to settings--> demoApp--> Notification and enabled alert,badge & sound,even then sound notification is not occuring**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing  it on Simulator? If it works in the Simulator and not in the device make sure the mute switch is not on

Answer (score 0):

Finally my problem got solved,

**1)** this line must be in your code,

```
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
```

**2)** make sure that the **donot disturb mode is "off"** (slide up your phone from bottom , you will see a half moon symbol)

**3)** This mistake is what I made -->> the phone was in silent mode ( on the side of your iphone there will be a *switch* **near** to the volume button's)

**4)** Go to settings --> notifications --> your application --> enable Allow notifications

**5)** Go to settings --> notifications --> your application --> enable sound

**6)** Increase your ringer volume by using the volume buttons on the side..

Hope this might help anyone else ..... :)